# About xml and php

Tags: php, xml

I have to insert the xml processing instruction into xml file without opening that file means i have to insert that through PHP.anyone please helpme.

Comment: It's probably just a matter of *your* definition of insert/open versus *my* definition, but I can't see how you can insert anything into a file *without* opening it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with "XML processing instruction" you mean basically something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Please note, that this is (as per spec) **no** processing instruction and will in all DOM tools never appear as one.

If you try to output this in PHP and find problems you most likely have the PHP.ini's [`short_open_tag`](http://de.php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive set to On. Two possibilities:

1. Set `short_open_tags = Off` in your php.ini
2. `echo` the stuff:

-

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'."\n";
```

Comment: What does this mean: "no processing instruction and will in all DOM tools never appear as one." ?

Comment: The definition of a processing instruction is [defined in the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) and is distinct from an [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl).

Comment: Yes and two paragrpahs before the *XML Declaration* is defined. So, XML Declaration != Processing Instruction.

Comment: If you don't trust me, perhaps [xml.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/09/04/xslt.html)?

Comment: Or XSLT: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt point 7.3 (sorry, I couldn't resist. I'll stop now.)

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done without opening the file. How else are you supposed to get the data? Even functions such as `file_get_contents()` cause the file to be opened, it just closes it again immediately after. If this is not what you mean by open you might want to edit your question.